# Mezzanine/django template rendering not calling model methods

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mezzanine

**TLDR**: Custom view/template only sometimes calls custom model method. Sometimes wrong result (with no print messages from method) and sometimes right result (with print messages from method).

I'm new to Mezzanine (more used to Pyramid) and am having a weird non-deterministic problem with some template rendering. I've created a Mezzanine project with a internal Django app for adding 3 new types: Experiment (Page, RichText), Instrument (Page, RichText), DailyStatus (Displayable, Ownable, RichText). I've defined a ForeignKey on the DailyStatus to link it to a single Experiment.

Since DailyStatus isn't a subclass of Page I've created my own view and my own template (extending base.html). This template takes a lot from the blog detail template since a DailyStatus serves a similar purpose. In the template I call two methods to get the previous and next DailyStatus within an Experiment (`get_previous_by_status_date` and `get_next_by_status_date`) which use the DailyStatus `status_date` DateField.

Sometimes when I visit a daily status page the prev/next buttons work as expected (showing the next status in an experiment or not showing any if first/last in an experiment). But other times, when the server restarts/reloads, it seems to be choosing the prev/next by publish_date or just not working. It never switches these states during a single instance of the server. I've used pdb and ipdb to try to debug this and have come to the point where calling `daily_status_inst.get_previous_by_status_date()` produces the wrong result and `daily_status_inst._get_next_or_previous_by_status_date(False)` produces the right result. The context between the correct state and wrong states doesn't seem to be any different (I dumped the dicts to a file). I've added print to the individual prev/next methods and sometimes they don't even seem to get called (no output) but they return an incorrect value.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Or any other helpful debug tips? My DailyStatus model is below:

```
class DailyStatus(Displayable, Ownable, RichText):
    experiment = models.ForeignKey(Experiment, related_name="daily_statuses")
    status_date = models.DateField(_("Status Date"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Daily Status")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Daily Statuses")
        ordering = ("-status_date",)
        order_with_respect_to = "experiment"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('daily_status_detail',
                       kwargs={
                           "experiment": self.experiment.slug,
                           "slug": self.slug,
                       })

    def _get_next_or_previous_by_status_date(self, is_next, **kwargs):
        arg = "status_date__gt" if is_next else "status_date__lt"
        order = "status_date" if is_next else "-status_date"
        lookup = {arg: self.status_date, "experiment": self.experiment}
        try:
            queryset = DailyStatus.objects.published
        except AttributeError:
            queryset = DailyStatus.objects.all
        try:
            dstatus = queryset(**kwargs).filter(**lookup).order_by(order)[0]
            return dstatus
        except IndexError:
            return False

    def get_next_by_status_date(self, **kwargs):
        dstatus = self._get_next_or_previous_by_status_date(True, **kwargs)
        return dstatus

    def get_previous_by_status_date(self, **kwargs):
        dstatus = self._get_next_or_previous_by_status_date(False, **kwargs)
        return dstatus
```

Simplest Template:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    {{ daily_status.get_previous_by_status_date }}
    <p></p>
    {{ daily_status.get_next_by_status_date }}
</body>
</html>
```

Using:

```
* Mezzanine 3.1.10
* Django 1.6.11
* Python 3.4.3
* SQLite 3.8.10.1
* Darwin 14.3.0
```

Thanks for any help.

**Update 1:**

I've tracked it down to the prev/next methods being `_curried` or not. When they are curried it never calls the actual method (or at least doesn't print any output). When it is the normal bound method I get the expected output:

```
# custom view
status_posts = DailyStatus.objects.published().filter(experiment__slug=experiment).all()
print(status_posts.get_next_by_status_date)
# get_object_or_404 and so on with rendering...

# print produces:
<bound method DailyStatus._curried of <DailyStatus: 2013: Update 1>>
# or (after a couple server restarts):
<bound method DailyStatus.get_next_by_status_date of <DailyStatus: 2013: Update 1>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while, but I figured it out. This all has to do with the magic of signals (I'm assuming based on the race condition nature of the problem) and the `contribute_to_class` methods. The proper model, or at least one working solution for what I was trying to do, is below.

When you create a `DateField` on a model and it is added to other objects (I think), it's [contribute_to_class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1276) method gets called which adds a `get_next_by_%s` and `get_previous_by_%s` method with the fields name. So when I was creating my methods with the `get_previous_by_status_date` name there was a race condition between the `contribute_to_class` method being added and my method being added. Since you can't call methods with arguments in templates I had to create new methods that automatically added the experiment filter.

If I'm wrong about anything **PLEASE** correct me. Good thing I'm not scared of reading source code.

```
class DailyStatus(Displayable, Ownable, RichText):
    experiment = models.ForeignKey(Experiment, related_name="daily_statuses")
    status_date = models.DateField(_("Status Date"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Daily Status")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Daily Statuses")
        ordering = ("-status_date",)
        order_with_respect_to = "experiment"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('daily_status_detail',
                       kwargs={
                           "experiment": self.experiment.slug,
                           "slug": self.slug,
                       })

    def get_next_by_status_date_exp(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Retrieves next object by status date.
        """
        kwargs.setdefault("experiment", self.experiment)
        return self.get_next_by_status_date(**kwargs)

    def get_previous_by_status_date_exp(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Retrieves previous object by status date.
        """
        kwargs.setdefault("experiment", self.experiment)
        return self.get_previous_by_status_date(**kwargs)
```

Comment: And I found the documentation that talks about this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO